# Redeem airdrop with smart contract

Tags: solidity, tokens, airdrop

Can an airdrop be allocated to a smart contract?

If yes, how would the smart contract claim the tokens?

Answer (score 1):

There can be different implementations for the `redeem` function so that you can directly `redeem` in `smart contract`. The simplest one is as below:

```
IERC20 token;
uint256 airdropAmount;
mapping(address => bool) public redeemed;

function redeem(address to) external {
 require(!redeemed[to], "already redeemed");
 require(!redeemed[msg.sender], "already redeemed");
 redeemed[msg.sender] = true;
 redeemed[to] = true;
 token.transfer(to, airdropAmount);
}
```

Now you can put smart contract address at the place of to and redeemed using your wallet so that token is transferred to the smart contract.

But, if you want your smart contract to redeem from other smart contract then you have to know the abi or inteface of that contract function. If, let's say redeem function in airdrop contract is like

```
function redem() external {}
```

Then you can implement this interface in your contract as below:

```
    interface Airdrop {
      function redeem() external;
    }
    
    contract AirdropClaim {
       Airdrop aidropContract = Airdrop("airdropContractAddress");
    
       function redeem() externanl {
         aidropContract.redeem();
    } 

}
```

Comment: You didn't get the question. By redeem, I meant claim an airdrop from a 3rd party. Like if X is doing an airdrop on usage of X and the user is Y which is a smart contract, will Y get any tokens allocated?

Comment: Then you can make the redeem() to send to the msg,sender and create a modifier to only allow certains address to perfom it.

Comment: Yes, the second code is for that purpose.